# Как передать команде элемент ListBox по кнопке которого было произведено нажатие?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня прописан ListBox такого типа:

```
              <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" Name="list">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                <Button Width="20" Height="30" Command="{Binding DeleteNoteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                        CommandParameter="???">Удалить</Button>                                
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

И мне нужно как-то передать в CommandParameter кнопки объект на котором была нажата эта кнопка

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` ?

Comment: Спасибо, не додумался бы что именно так передается текущий элемент